# Injected functions not working on content and background.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following situation.
I have the contents.js file and background.js.
And I inject the file inject.js which is where are the functions that run things in the browser.

I created a listener in the background, because I need to make an external request.
Regarding this, okay. I send a content message, it arrives in the background and the background searches on my server.
This all works okay.
However I now need an inject function to be executed.
But neither content nor background can "see" functions.

How do I perform a function injected into the content or background?

Comment: "Injected" is a vague and broad term so without MCVE we can't really help here.

Comment: [MCVE](/help/mcve) would be manifest.json and relevant excerpts from the files you mentioned.